# Threaded quicksort

Tags: java, multithreading, quicksort, executorservice

Hello I've never tried using threads before, this is my first attempt but it doesn't stop, The normal verion works.
if I remove awaitTermination it looks like it works but I need the method to finish when it's all sorted out(pun intended XD).
Can you tell me what I did wrong?
Thank you.

```
public class Sorting {

  private Sorting() {};

  private static Random r = new Random();
  private static int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
  private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);

  public static void qsortP(int[] a) {
    qsortParallelo(a, 0, a.length - 1);
  }

  private static void qsortParallelo(int[] a, int first, int last) {
    while (first < last) {
      int p = first + r.nextInt(last - first + 1);
      int px = a[p];
      int i = first, j = last;
      do {
        while (a[i] < px)
          i++;
        while (a[j] > px)
          j--;
        if (i <= j) {
          scambia(a, i++, j--);
        }
      } while (i <= j);
      executor.submit(new qsortThread(a, first, j));
      first = i;
    }
    try {
      executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static void scambia(int[] a, int x, int y) {
    int temp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = temp;
  }

  public static class qsortThread implements Runnable {
    final int a[], first, last;

    public qsortThread(int[] a, int first, int last) {
      this.a = a;
      this.first = first;
      this.last = last;
    }

    public void run() {
      qsortParallelo(a, first, last);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting for termination of the entire executor service (which probably isn't what you want at all), you should save all the `Future`s returned by `executor.submit()` and wait until they're all done (by calling 'get()` on them for example).

And though it's tempting to do this in the `qsortParallelo()` method, that would actually lead to a deadlock by exhaustion of the thread pool: parent tasks would hog the worker threads waiting for their child tasks to complete, but the child tasks would never be scheduled to run because there would be no available worker threads.

So you have to collect all the `Future` objects into a concurrent collection first, return the result to `qsortP()` and wait there for the `Future`s to finish.

Or use a `ForkJoinPool`, which was designed for exactly this kind of task and does all the donkey work for you. Recursively submitting tasks to an executor from application code is generally not a very good idea, it's very easy to get it wrong.

---

As an aside, the reason your code is deadlocked as it is is that every worker thread is stuck in `executor.awaitTermination()`, thereby preventing the termination of the executor service.

In general, the two most useful tools for designing and debugging multi-threaded applications are:

1. A thread dump. You can generate that with [`jstack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html), VisualVM or any other tool, but it's invaluable in deadlock situations, it gives you an accurate image of what's (not) going on with your threads.
2. A pen, a piece of paper and drawing a good old fashioned swimlane chart.

Comment: I used ForkJoinPool and now it works perfectly, I was just wondering, what happend if I use up the pool and need more threads?

Comment: @grecof88 There's usually no point having more threads in the pool than you have CPUs. The reason for that is that `ForkJoinPool` is implemented using "work stealing": the forked tasks will try to run on the same thread if possible, but if there's a thread in the pool that has nothing to do, it will "steal" a task from another thread's queue. Which means that unless your tasks are I/O bound, your CPUs will be more or less maxed out.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `executor.awaitTermination` inside a `Thread` which was launched by your `executor`. `Thread` will not stop until `executor` comes out of the `awaitTermination` and `executor` will not come out of `awaitTermination` until the `Thread` terminates. You need to move this code:

```
try {
  executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

into the end of `qsortP` method.

Comment: Tryed it, still goes on forever, I read online that I need to use the shutdown method before awaitTermination, but if I do it I can't call any more threads. I don't know where to put it and still call all the threads that I need.

Comment: Yes, you need to call `executor.shutdown();`  before `awaitTermination`, but you will not be able to use this `executor` for new launches. So you need to create new `executor` every time you call the `qsortP` method. You can put `executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);` in the begin of `qsortP`.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in this code is simply the while-loop in `qsortParallelo`. `first` and `last` are never modified. Apart from that you don't need the while-loop, since you already do that the further sorting in the executor. And you'll need to start another task for the second half of the array.

Comment: first is modified after the first submit: first = i;